# LINQ expressions add unnecessary parentheses

Tags: c#, .net, expression, linq-expressions

I'm building a LINQ expression in C# like this:

```
public static Expression BuildEqualsExpression(
    ParameterExpression Parameter,
    PropertyInfo Property,
    ConstantExpression constant)
{
    Expression propertyExpression = Expression.Property(Parameter, Property);
    return Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, constant);
}
```

The returned Expression is

```
(r.Property == constant)
```

when what I want is

```
r.Property == constant
```

without the parentheses. My `IQueryProvider` does not treat these two statements equally. Does anyone know how I can get rid of the parentheses?

If I `AND` two of these together, I get

```
((r.Property1 == constant) And (r.Property2 == constant))
```

when I want

```
r.Property1 == constant And r.Property2 == constant
```

since they are not equivalent predicates.

Edit:

Thanks for your help.  It turns out that in SQL server 2014, using this command:

```
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

When the number of actual rows is < 100, this will cause the query to execute extremely slowly.

Comment: That's just the string representation of the expression, it doesn't change its meaning. And yes, the two predicates *are* equivalent. Does your IQueryProvider work on the string representation?

Comment: The backing store of my IQueryProvider does not treat these equivalently.  I need no parenthesis.  Even though mathematically they are equivalent, the backing store treats parenthesis as a specific operation =\

Comment: @Magn3s1um: With all due respect, that makes no sense. What operation do the parenthesis perform, then?

Comment: It changes the operation to a greedy operation, which changes the execution plan.

Comment: @Magn3s1um, the parentheses are not part of the expression tree, they're only visible when you stringify the expression. Your IQueryProvider should work with the expression tree, not the string representation. To do that, I suggest you look into the Visitor pattern, and more specifically the [ExpressionVisitor class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

There are no LINQ expression nodes that explicitly represent parentheses. Instead, operator precedence and associativity are automatically inferred from the structure of the expression tree.

It seems that either you or the query provider is calling ToString() on the expression. **Don't do this.** The [expression trees specification](http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=dlr&DownloadId=246539) states:

> Expression.ToString is for light weight debugging purposes only. [...]
>
> ToString does not try to return semantically accurate C# or VB code in particular.  We try to return terse strings loosely suggesting what an ET [expression tree] node contains for quick inspection only.

As Thomas Levesque notes in a comment, the best approach is for the query provider to work directly with expression trees instead of strings.

If the query provider only accepts strings, then you'll have to convert the expression to a string yourself. Your task will be complicated by the fact that extra parentheses are problematic, because you still need to insert parentheses to distinguish, say, (1 + 2) * 3 from 1 + (2 * 3).

Here's some code to get you started:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<ExpressionType, string> s_binaryOperators =
    new Dictionary<ExpressionType, string>
    {
        { ExpressionType.Equal, " == " },
        { ExpressionType.And, " AND " },
    };

public static void ToString(Expression expression, StringBuilder builder)
{
    switch (expression.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Parameter:
            builder.Append(((ParameterExpression)expression).Name);
            break;

        case ExpressionType.Constant:
            builder.Append(((ConstantExpression)expression).Value);
            break;

        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
            // TODO: Add parentheses if memberExpression.Expression.NodeType
            // has lower precedence than the current expression.
            ToString(memberExpression.Expression, builder);
            builder.Append('.').Append(memberExpression.Member.Name);
            break;

        case ExpressionType.Equal:
        case ExpressionType.And:
            var binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)expression;
            // TODO: Add parentheses if binaryExpression.Left.NodeType
            // has lower precedence than the current expression.
            ToString(binaryExpression.Left, builder);
            builder.Append(s_binaryOperators[expression.NodeType]);
            // TODO: Add parentheses if binaryExpression.Right.NodeType
            // has lower precedence than the current expression.
            ToString(binaryExpression.Right, builder);
            break;

        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Entity framework does place parentheses around the predicates in the where clause (express 1) and (expression 2).  This slows the query down tremendously.  Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of a SQL query where the presence or absence of parentheses affects the execution plan? Also, what version of SQL Server are you using? (This would be a good candidate for a new question because the existence of such a query would contradict [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525938/1127114).)

Comment: Yeah I can.  Easily reproducible.